# React multi-select cannot pass selected data, Instead passing all the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, multi-select

I'm using react-multiselect by @kenshooui/react-multi-select and in the DOCs the example is a class based component but I'm using functional based in my JS code. 
Code for multi-select is

```
 <MultiSelect
  items={form.states}
  selectedItems={form.selectedItems}
  onChange={handleChange} />
```

In this I'm having problem in function handleChange. I tried to change the function from class based to function based but its not working
the function in docs is:

```
    this.setState({ selectedItems });
  }
```

In this function `selectedItems`'s state is changed with all the items which are selected in frontend.
What I tried with this is:

```
const handleChange = (selectedItems)=> {
        setForm.selectedItems=selectedItems;
        console.log(selectedItems, "selectedItemsssssss");

    };
```

Meanwhile I have a handleInputChange function also:

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        setForm({
            ...form,
            [name]: value,

        });
    };
```

Please help me with this. How to change state of selectedItems and send data to backend. I'm new to react.

Comment: What is `setForm` and where is it coming from? can you provide a minimal codesandbox demonstrating the issue?

Comment: setForm is :
```
 const [form, setForm] = useState({....'origin': '',
        'destination': '',
        'scheduled_date': '',
        'truck_type': '',
        'truck_name': '',
        'total_trucks': 0,
        'offered_price': 0,
        'weight': 0,
 states: [
            { id: 1, label: "All_India" },
            { id: 2, label: "Andhra_Pradesh" },
            { id: 3, label: "Assam"},
            { id: 4, label: "Bihar" },
            { id: 5, label: "Chandigarh" },
            { id: 6, label: "Chhattisgarh" },
            { id: 7, label: "Delhi" },
```

Comment: @wrsx I want a new function handInput which changes the state of selectedItems from an empty array to array with selected states

Comment: If setForm is a function, then setForm.selectedItems=selectedItems looks wrong. Its hard to provide any sort of answer without a codesandbox. Can you please provide one? https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-mendel-henf2

Comment: But Its not working on sandbox because import statements cannot fetch imports for obvious reasons @wrsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setForm` is a setter function returned from `useState` which should take your new state. In your case, you are trying to assign the property `selectedItems` to this function:

```
const handleChange = (selectedItems) => {
  setForm.selectedItems=selectedItems;
};
```

You should instead call the function with your updated state:

```
const handleChange = selectedItems => {
  setForm({ ...form, selectedItems });
};
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-feistel-h21dj)